# protobuf options - how to enforce "use only these data types" in the .proto file

Tags: protocol-buffers, proto

I want to enforce that a `.proto` file uses only "approved" data types (custom-defined types are valid).

**QUESTION**
Is there a `.proto`-file level option where I can say **use only: fixed32, fixed64, and any custom messages**

Also, I would want to enforce that all `bytes` types use `fixed_length = true`

I know I can do this by parsing each file using Python but I'd prefer a builtin option.

Comment: Aside from DazWilkin's answer,  there is the point that really, as an interface definition, there should be only one owner of it. In principle it should be up to the interface owner, and only the owner, to make changes to the content. It is therefore within the gift of the owner to exercise appropriate self discipline in the matter, and for everyone else the .proto file should be read only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way this could be enforced is through some form of style-enforcement (linting) when protos are checked in to your source control or prior to `protoc` compilation.

I don't use it but [`buf lint`](https://docs.buf.build/lint/overview) may help.